# Getting RSSI values between two B210 USRP to print on a text file

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, usrp

I have been using Gnuradio for a while and wanted to print the RSSI values to a text file as received from the other USRP. My objective is to print RSSI values from one transmitting USRP to another receiving USRP. I had read this thread. My setup is
USRP source---> complex to mag2---> log10---> Signal Probe

https://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/fkmrpo/need_help_with_gnuradio_graph_getting_rssi_values/

Although I am not exactly sure how to print the obtained values on a text file ?? I am using carrier frequency of 3.75 Ghz and sampling rate of 512k.

After adding the File Sink Block my setup is now:

USRP source---> complex to mag2---> log10--->Float to Char ---> File Sink.

The reason I am using the Signal Probe block was to see how my output was looking.                                                                                                                                When I open the file, using python, the file length is  too much(24 MB).So I added the Throttle block, this results the overall size of the file to be less as before.

The file, however, is extremely large.

Comment: Please do not post new questions as answers.  Instead, open a new question.  Additionally, I am editing this question to remove your new question since it "pollutes" the original question and invalidates the answers people took the time to write.

Comment: I am downvoting this question. Even though I think the question is useful, the way it is asked is unfocused and updates seem to ignore provided answers.

Comment: i'm having a hard time understanding what the actual question is here. I've placed a close vote.

Answer (score 2):

"RSSI" isn't something that is universally defined – it's a *signal strength/quality indicator for a specific signal type*. Thus, without saying what waveform you consider signal (and what noise), you can't make *any* statements on RSSI!

Anyways, you're not even trying to do that:

> USRP source---> complex to mag2---> log10---> Signal Probe

That's just logarithmic digital power, based on full-scale digital output. That's fine, but don't call it "RSSI", it's not. You can call it "power", but until you've calibrated your specific SDR setup, you don't know what a power of "1.0" (or its logarithm of 0) is. It's *proportional to physical power*.

Anyway, the Signal Probe is **never** the block you want. Never. Seriously. You just want to write the values to a file, so use the File Sink.

> print the RSSI values to a text file as received

What would you do with 512,000 numbers per second in a text file? That makes no sense; it quickly grows very big¹, or you incur serious rounding error, it's slow to write and to read, *and in no reality ever* is a human able to read a couple million values in a text editor and learn anything useful. [I go into more detail why text-based sample storage is a bad idea here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76037618/4433386)

So, just use the *File Sink* block. Its [wiki page](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=File_Sink) describes how to read the values from the files it writes in (currently) 4 programming languages (Matlab/Octave, Python, C and C++); every other serious general-purpose programming language that I'm aware of can also load such files using very similar functionality.

---

¹ because text to store numbers is very inefficient; writing a float as handled here at full precision takes about 12 to 16 Byte per text value, e.g. `2.397843E-03,`; whereas just storing the float takes 4 Bytes.

Comment: How to properly calibrate the SDRs in order to get "power" as you mentioned. Is There a website tutorial that I can follow. As far as I am aware, from getting the power value, we can get the RSSI. Can you also provide some methods to determine the RSSI (example a relevant website,article or research paper) through which I can move further with my project. Thank You!

Comment: *How to properly calibrate the SDRs in order to get "power" as you mentioned* you need to connect a source of known power. Then, the power of that gives you the reference value.

Comment: *As far as I am aware, from getting the power value, we can get the RSSI* **no,** literally my answer's first sentence.

Comment: *Can you also provide some methods to determine the RSSI* I wrote that it's specific to the nature of your signal / system. There **is no** general definition of RSSI. You need to find a definition that suits your specific use case